# Removing rows to reduce the rank

Tags: reference-request, matrices, finite-fields

What is the smallest number of rows one can delete from a matrix to reduce its rank (by $1$)? Is there any standard name / notation for this characteristic? Has it been studied?

I am in fact interested in the matrices over the prime-order field $\mathbb F_p$ of the following special kind. Fix an integer $d\approx 10\sqrt p$ and field elements $v_0,\dotsc,v_{p-1}\in\mathbb F_p$. The $p$ rows of the matrix correspond to the elements $k\in\mathbb F_p$, the $d^2$ columns correspond to the pairs $(i,j)\in[0,d-1]^2$, and the elements are given by $M_{k,(i,j)}=k^iv_k^j$. Can one remove $O(\sqrt p)$ rows from this matrix to have its rank dropped?

I suspect that the answer depends on the specific choice of $v_0,\dotsc,v_{p-1}$; if it does, then how exactly it depends?