# Largest subset not spanning the span

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-optimization

Let $S=\{c_1,\dots,c_n\}$ be a set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^M$. Is the below problem studied in literature?
$$\max\limits_{S'\subset S} \vert S' \vert $$
$$s.t. dim(span(S')) < dim(span(S))$$

which is to find the cardinality of the largest subset which does not span the span of S.

Comment: I won't be surprised if this is NP-hard.

Comment: I asked this question a while ago: https://mathoverflow.net/q/339819/9924 There were no replies, and somehow I convinced myself that no reasonable answer exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a matroid theory question. If you let $S$ be the ground set of the matroid and you let $r$ be the rank of the matroid (i.e. $\dim \mathrm{span}(S)$), then your question amounts to finding the largest flat of rank $r-1$.

For reference, I would recommend Oxley's Matroid Theory.

That said, one generally cares more about finding the entire lattice of flats or a maximal chain of flats than a particular one. But to answer your question, flats, in general, are of particular interest in matroid theory. There are a number of tools for finding flats as well.